# Populating relationship table randomly from two entity tables Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm attempting a simple E-R where the two entity sets are : Student & University each having about 200rows & the relationship to be "Applies" [so student applies to university]

I have the student table with a few data but the Primary Key being Student_ID

the University has Univeristy_Name as the PK;

now the relationship - "applies" - I have the student_ID & University_Name as FK & application_ID as PK

I have to populate this "applies" table containing about 10% chosen at random of the possible relationship, using one single INSERT statement & maybe a "random()" function. Does anyone know how do I go about populating the table using values from the other two tables randomly?

Comment: I think you could make use of `ORDER BY random()` and `LIMIT` when selecting from students. For each selected student you can select an university using the same mechanism just `LIMIT 1`. 200 rows is a such a small number, the performance of a query should not concern you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use:

```
insert into applies (student_id, university_name)
    select s.student_id, u.university_name
    from students s cross join
         universities u
    order by random()
    limit 4000;
```

Alternatively, you can do this without sorting using:

```
insert into applies (student_id, university_name)
    select s.student_id, u.university_name
    from students s cross join
         universities u
    where random() < 0.1;
```

Note that this is an approximate 10% sample of the rows rather than an exact count.

Comment: This worked perfectly! thank you so much for the help! I will look at the other method without sorting too and try playing around with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your case with

```
create table students (student_id serial primary key, name varchar);
create table university (University_Name varchar primary key);
insert into students (name) values ('Francesco');
insert into students (name) values ('Laura');
insert into students (name) values ('Christian');
insert into students (name) values ('Ugo');
insert into students (name) values ('Maria');
insert into students (name) values ('Antonietta');

insert into university values ('Bocconi');
insert into university values ('Universita di Pisa');
insert into university values ('Universita di Padova');
insert into university values ('Universita di Perugia');
```

If you don't have any limits in students applying for multiple universities, you could achieve the insert with

```
select * from students cross join university order by random() limit 3;
```

Where `limit 3` displays only 3 rows

Comment: `JOIN` is short for `INNER JOIN` and requires an `ON` clause, because inner joins join on a condition. Using `ON 1 = 1` works to actually cross join the tables instead, i.e. join without a condition, but is unnecessarily akward, because all you really want is a `CROSS JOIN`, not a `INNER JOIN`. Use `FROM students CROSS JOIN university` hence.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross join the two tables to get all combinations of student and university. Then number your rows in random order and keep those with a number <= the number of total rows divided by ten to keep 10% of those combinations:

```
insert into applies (student_id, university_name)
  select student_id, university_name
  from
  (
    select 
      s.student_id, 
      u.university_name,
      row_number() over (order by random()) as rn,
      count(*) over () as cnt
    from student s 
    cross join university u
  ) randomized
  where rn <= cnt / 10.0;
```